# How to make full text search with mongodb spring data?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, full-text-search, spring-data-mongodb

Before asking this question, I have searched much about my problem. I need to make full text search from mongodb in spring framework. Up to now I just tried something with regex, but it does not cover my requirement. **For example, I have a search string as 'increased world population' , and my search algorithm should return documents well-matched to search string or documents including at least one word from search string.** I know Lucene does full text search, but I don't know how to implement it with my mongodb spring data and I dont know whether spring data already offer full text search. I need a tutorial which explain that.
what I have done up to now:

```
Criteria textCriteri = Criteria.where("title").regex(searchStr.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "), "i");
Query query = new Query(locationCriteria).addCriteria(textCriteri).limit(Consts.MONGO_QUERY_LIMIT);
List<MyObject> advs = mongoTemplate.find(query, MyObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'text' index in mongodb and search through that, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Depending on your search queries, you probably want to use a more powerful search engine like ElasticSearch (as you mentioned Lucene).

Comment: I have already set text index for title field in my collection. I just do not know how to write my query then or using lucene. Or if it is possible to do that(like I highlighted in my question) with regex, I can use it also. Because I dont need very powerfull searc now.